# How to debug random hangs

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, error-handling, visual-studio-2015

We have C# .NET 4.0 application loading data from XML files.

During debugging application randomly "hangs" for a period of time (> 20 seconds). It could be during data loading or after data is already loaded.

If I try to stop Visual studio with PAUSE (Break All) button, visual studio Hangs, Threads windows stays empty, like there is no active threads.
Problem started to apear when we upgraded from VS2013 to VS2015.

How do you suggest that I start to debug the problem?

Comment: You can't debug anti-malware, you can only disable it.  Avast is especially popular this week, uninstall it completely.

Answer (score -1):

If it hangs often or with any predictability, you should be able to find the problem using [procmon.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Just start a capture when you begin debugging in Studio, then sift through the messages when it hangs.

Comment: Why the down vote? I gave my answer based on experience. I always turn to procmon in these cases.